# "Encadrer le crédit à la consommation" ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

L'une des définitions du mot *encadrer* selon *Le Petit Robert* est :

> Donner un cadre légal à quelque chose (ex. encadrer le crédit à la consommation).

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer ce que veut dire *encadrer le crédit à la consommation ?* Je ne comprends vraiment pas.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu ne comprends pas ? L'emploi du mot encadrer dans cette expression, ou l'expression « [crédit à la consommation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A9dit_%C3%A0_la_consommation) » ?

Comment: Elle ne comprends pas comment il puisse exister déjà un crédit à la consommation sans cadre légal. Alors s'agirait-il plutôt de changer le cadre légal existant ? Je ne comprends pas non plus. Il faudrait le contexte d'abord pour essayer de voir ce qui est vraiment dit.

Comment: L'abus du crédit à la consommation peut mener à des situations de surendettement. "Encadrer le crédit à la consommation" est souvent utilisé pour signifier qu'il faut "obliger" les prêteurs à vérifier la solvabilité de leurs clients avant d'accorder un tel crédit.

Comment: @LPH Tu as encore des problèmes avec le subjonctif. En français on dit *Elle ne comprend pas comment il **peut** exister*, pas *comment il **puisse***.

Comment: @Laure Les deux.

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, c'est un usage très minoritaire, mais on en trouve des cas, bien que beaucoup soient dans la langue ancienne ; en voilà un récent : « Mais je ne comprends pas comment il puisse trouver l'argumentation de M. Hûllmann pressante (hlemmend). Elle est si peu pressante qu'elle n'est pas même spécieuse » ; il faudrait que j'y pense.

Comment: @LPH Récent ? 1840. L'auteur traduit du néerlandais et a manifestement utilisé par erreur *comment* pour *que*.

Comment: @jlliagre Je crois plutôt que cela vient de l'ancienne langue, dans laquelle c'est un peu plus courant ; mais il est probablement plus logique d'utiliser l'indicatif ; il faudra que j'y pense.

Comment: @jlliagre Encore en 1840, mais directement composé en français: «Je ne conçois pas comment il [puisse](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5690122v/f25.item.r=%22pas%20comment%20il%20puisse%22.texteImage) exister dans la société des personnes qui se vantent de leur parfaite santé et de leur bravoure imprudente, pendant que continuellement elles suivent des régimes qui ne devraient avoir lieu, si elles sont véritablement bien portantes.» Ça ne m’écorche pas particulièrement les oreilles.

Comment: @LPH Avec le verbe *être*, je ne trouve pas la tournure particulièrement malsaine, mais elle est néanmoins un peu surprenante: *«Elle ne comprend pas comment il soit possible qu’un crédit à la consommation pût exister sans cadre légal.»* Je ne sais trop qu’en penser moi non plus...

Comment: @Montéedelait Le verbe lui-même marquerait déjà qu'il s'agit  de ce qui est dans le possible mais non vérifié ; il y aurait donc redondance. C'est une idée, mais sans autre fondement que sa logique.

Comment: @Montéedelait Le subjonctif est illogique après *comment* qui signifie *de quelle manière* et qui ne devrait être suivi que d'un fait considéré comme établi (indicatif: *je ne comprends pas comment il peut*) ou hypothétique (conditionnel: *Je ne comprends pas comment il pourrait*). J'ai du mal à trouver des références mais je ne suis pas le seul à trouver le subjonctif incorrect ici: http://chouxdesiam.canalblog.com/archives/2010/12/12/19851554.html

Comment: @jlliagre Ça me semble une grande question, mais je sens que le cas semble réglé d’avance pour vous. Je me trouve dans la position de LPH, qui ne sait trop comment exprimer ou justifier ce qui ne lui semble pas foncièrement incorrect. Peut-être le subjonctif est-il l’expression de l’incompréhension la plus totale, de l’impossibilité de concevoir un mécanisme logique qui eût généré ce qui est néanmoins avéré? Je puis être d’accord que le fait est établi, mais si son établissement me semble, disons, le fruit du chaos plutôt que de la raison, j’utiliserais alors le subjonctif pour l’exprimer.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne déclare bien sûr pas avoir raison, mais ça explique un peu la façon dont je le perçois. Par l’emploi du subjonctif, on remet en question le fait que l’établissement constaté ait été le fait de la raison, ce qui nous permet de proposer de le reconstruire. Ça me semble recevable dans un discours qui se veut argumentatif. On y déclare entre les lignes quelque chose comme: «Je nie cet état des faits, même s’il est établi, constaté, mesuré, indéniable. Je le nie parce qu’il est contraire au bon sens, et que seul un mécanisme anarchique aurait pu le mettre en place.»

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Encadrer* peut aussi être employé dans le sens *réguler*,*contrôler*.
D'après le contexte, c'est effectivement le cas, puisque le crédit à la consommation bénéficie déjà d'un cadre légal.

Il s'agit plutôt de le réguler pour éviter les abus, les situations de surendettement, etc...